# How do you get a location capturer to run before an override segue?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, core-location, cllocationmanager

So, I need to capture user's location (with their permission of course) before he gets to homepage. So on the login/register page I want to capture the location, but I need to do it before the override segue to homepage for logged in users. Any of you have any ideas? Below is the override segue.

I put location capturer before the segue in the override function, but it still went to homepage before the user had an opportunity to accept share location. This is not really unexpected since the entire override function is by definition an override function

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
//////////////////////
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    latestLocation = ["latitude" : locValue.latitude, "longitude" : locValue.longitude]
    let lat = locValue.latitude
    let lon = locValue.longitude
    dict = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    print("dict", dict)
    if let locationDictionary = latestLocation {           
databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").setValue(locationDictionary)  
    }   
}
//////////////////////
 if  Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Update: This is how I login and register.

```
    @IBAction func RegisterPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: (emailField.text ?? ""), password: (passwordField.text ?? ""))  { (user, error) in
            if let _eror = error {
                //something bad happning
                print(_eror.localizedDescription )
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid Entry or Duplicate.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(action)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }else{
                //user registered successfully
                print(user as Any)
                if let userID = user?.user.uid
                {
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((userID), forKey: "uid")
                    
                    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                    
                    databaseRef.child("A1").child(userID).child("users").setValue(self.emailField.text!)
                    databaseRef.child("people").child(userID).child("postID").setValue(userID)
                    let components = self.emailField.text!.split(separator: "@")
                    let child1 = components[0] //will be jake
                    let child2 = components[1] //will be aol.com
                    print(components, child1, child2, "childs")
                    databaseRef.child("people").child(userID).child("e2").setValue(child2)


                    components.forEach { print($0) }
                    
                    
                    

                    
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
     @IBAction func loginInPressed(_ sender: Any) {
 Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: (emailField.text ?? ""), password: (passwordField.text ?? ""))  { (user, error) in
    if let _eror = error {
                   //something bad happning
                   print(_eror.localizedDescription )
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Incorrect Email or Password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                                     let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                                     alert.addAction(action)
                                     self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

               }else{
                   //user registered successfully
                   print(user as Any)
                        if let userID = user?.user.uid
 {
                            KeychainWrapper.standard.set((userID), forKey: "uid")
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil) }

               }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly in `viewDidAppear(_:)` you have one condition. If it's `true` you immediately trying to perform the segue.

```
if  Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)
}
```

As location is must to move into `HomeScreen`, why don't you do the navigation(`segue`) when you receive the first location update inside `CLLocationManagerDelegate`?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   {
      // check for existing location if we received earlier
      guard self.latestLoc == nil else {
         // we received one location earlier, navigation to Home completed. no need to proceed 
         // If we no longer need to listen for loc updates, we can stop listening further
         manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
         return
      } 
      // ... Your exiting data base update code
     guard let latestLoc = locations.last else { return }
     self.latestLoc = latestLoc // If you want to pass this location to destination view controller in `prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`
     // Also it will good practice to call manager.stopUpdatingLocation() if you need location only for once 

     // Now move to HomeScreen
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)

     // If we no longer need to listen for loc updates, we can stop listening further
     manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: hmm that may work. How would you define latestLoc in that case - as CLLocation? As for if it gets passed to destination VC; I don't think per se. This registers in firebase the user's location. The after "toHome" segue, the next page uses that firebase entry

Comment: I defined it as CLLocation and it seems to work. Only question is about `prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` If I put all the code in an `override func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, it doesn't automatically segue after saying allow this time. If I don't use `prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, will the location still be used before the next page (that the segue leads to) loads?

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. Only issue is that sometimes it reloads twice on the home screen (destination of tohome). It never did that before. I assume it has to do with cache from a previous build being the first thing that gets segued to. Or do you think it has something to do with `prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`?

Comment: So you are now facing a new problem which is seguing to `HomeScreen` twice from the screen where you are listening for location update. If this is the case, you can simply check if you already have a location from a previous delegate call back. `self.latestLoc = latestLoc` by this you can save latest location. You can simply return early if you have already received a location and screen navigation is already done.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, but what did you define latestLoc as? It can't be CLLocation cause then it gives error `Comparing non-optional value of type 'CLLocation' to 'nil' always returns false` Does it then have to be a string?

Comment: In ViewController, you should declare `latestLoc` as optional `var` i.e. `var latestLoc: CLLocation?`

Comment: facepalm, my bad, forgot to make it an optional yesterday. This works now. Thanks

Comment: So I discovered another issue that this solution causes. When signing a user out and closing the app: the next time you open the app, accept single use location location usage, and sign in again or register a new user, the page segues twice as well. Do you know why that might be? In the additional question edit is how I login and register.